# Check query string on the request using requests_mock

Tags: python, python-requests, requests-mock

How to check if a request mocked by requests_mock added some query parameters to a URL?

I have a function `func` thats do a HTTP POST on the url with some query string on the URL and I want to check if was called with this query string.

This is my attempt, but fails.

`query` is a empty string and `qs` is a empty dict.

I have sure that my func is appending the query string on the request.

```
with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock:
    mock.post(url, text=xml)

    func() # This function will call url + query string

    history = mock.request_history[0]

    assert history.method == "POST" # OK
    assert history.query is None # Returns an empty string, AssertionError: assert '' is None
    assert history.qs is None # Returns an empty dict, assert {} is None
```

My `func`

```
def credilink():
    url = settings["url"]
    params = settings["params"]
    params["CC"] = query

    response = requests.post(url, params=params)
    # ...
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example? I'm having some trouble understanding how you are using this. A single file script demonstrating the observed behavior and a comment about the expected behavior would be ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your problem and was unable to...

Here is the code I'm running:

```py
import requests
import requests_mock

url = "http://example.com"
settings = dict(url=url, params=dict(a=1))
query = "some-query"
xml = "some-xml"


def credilink():
    url = settings["url"]
    params = settings["params"]
    params["CC"] = query

    response = requests.post(url, params=params)
    return response.text
    # ...


def test():
    with requests_mock.Mocker() as mock:
        mock.post(url, text=xml)

        data = credilink()  # This function will call url + query string

        history = mock.request_history[0]

        assert history.method == "POST"  # OK
        assert history.qs == dict(a=['1'], cc=[query])
        assert history.query == f"a=1&cc={query}"
        assert data == xml
```

The assertions pass in this snippet.
Maybe it's some version problem? I used requests==2.25.1 and requests-mock==1.8.0.

Comment: I am using the same version

pip freeze | grep requests
requests==2.25.1
requests-mock==1.8.0

Comment: and the code i've written does not pass for you? :(

Comment: Nope. My `.qs` and `.query` still empty

Comment: . well, maybe python version? unlikely but still worth the try...

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.5. May be can something else in my code... I will accept your answer because I think it is correct. Thanks

Comment: checked with 3.8.5 and it works. thanks for accepting, but I still don't understand :O

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the problem was in `mock://` URL schema, as it's present in the `requests-mock` samples

```
session.get('mock://test.com/path')
```

But `requests` library skips query arguments for non "http" URLs. Here is the comment from the [source code](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/main/requests/models.py#L428)

```py
# Don't do any URL preparation for non-HTTP schemes like `mailto`,
# `data` etc to work around exceptions from `url_parse`, which
# handles RFC 3986 only.
if ':' in url and not url.lower().startswith('http'):
    self.url = url
    return
```